# How do I deallocate all derived dynamic memory of a member?

Tags: c++

Say I have a class:

```
struct foo{
    foo* bar=nullptr;
};
```

Now if I use new to allocate memory like a chain:

```
foo instance;
instance.bar= new foo;
instance.bar->bar=new foo;
...
```

Then how can I delete all those children of `instance` in a single call to delete the top level `instance`, i.e. when I call `destroy(instance); //dummy name` then all those dynamically allocated memory are all freed?

Comment: Why are using `_` as a variable name - not that descriptive.

Comment: @Ed Heal, I didn't come up with a name then, so you just edit it.

Comment: You could store all instances in some other container? Or you could add a destructor that deletes `bar`? Or think a bit more about the [*actual* problem you want to solve](http://xyproblem.info/), and come up with another solution or even another design? Or use a [standard container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) to begin with?

Comment: I'd suggest using smart pointers instead of manual memory management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may get used to std::unique_ptr (or std::shared_ptr, if needed):

```
#include <memory>
struct foo{
    std::unique_ptr<foo> bar;
};

int main() {
    // Please do not use '_' as a variable name.
    // (Some people do: #define _(T) gettext(T) // for gnu gettext support)
    foo _;
    _.bar = std::make_unique<foo>();
    _.bar->bar = std::make_unique<foo>();
    // ... the destructor will deallocate.
}
```

However, assuming `foo` has a data member (structure) T, you may consider a single linked list:

```
#include <forward_list>
std::forward_list<T> foo_list;
```

Which leads to related questions like: [Remove all nodes in linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662738/remove-all-nodes-in-linked-list)

Answer (score 0):

First you should define your problem correctly.

1. What does copying foo mean? will every thing being deeply coped?
2. Is this type movable?
3. Can a child foo live without its parent?

I will take a general case and answer your question based on it:

1. Copying is a deep copy.
2. It is movable.
3. Yes

This the solution based on the constraints:

```
struct foo{
    foo()=default;
    foo(foo const& other){
        bar=new foo(*other.bar);
    }
    foo(foo&& other){
        bar=other.bar;
        other.bar=nullptr;
    }
    ~foo(){
        delete bar;
    }
    foo* bar=nullptr;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a destructor to your struct foo.

```
struct foo{
    foo* bar=nullptr;
    ~foo() {delete bar;}
};
```

When the instance of foo goes out of scope, the destructor will be called and delete bar.

Comment: Now, you have to follow the rule of 3 or 5.